# About HDD enclosure

Tags: external-hard-drive, enclosures

I have this 3.5" IDE enclosure, and it works great, I mean I love the idea of enclosures ( not the power feeding thing :), btw can't I just insert a chargable battery to feed the power when I am unable to find an electricity block), anyway my question is, when I finish the usage of the enclosure I safely remove it when using Windows or umount when working with Linux, and after that I got confused whether to turn it off or no?

when I turn it off, the HDD suddenly stop spinning as if power failure not as when it was an internal and normally shuted down the pc.

So is it ok to turn it off the way I've just said???

regards,
~Abed

Answer (score 1):

Once the disk is unmounted, you can just switch off the disk.

Comment: thnx and just ignore the sound? it won't damage the sectors or so???

Comment: Well, once it is unmounted it should have no activity. If you want to be sure, wait a few seconds after unmounting so the disk gets some time to stop spinning.

Comment: define spinning???
cause when I am reading or writing through it it spins like a crazy b**ch but after safley removing it, it still spins but slowly so shall I wait for a minute for example???

Comment: There will always be some "activity", but the spinning speed should no longer vary after unmounting, it should be spinning at a constant pace.